# Tkinter Grid Layout Widget not in parent

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, grid-layout

I am building a GUI in Python with Tkinter however I am having issues with the Grid layout. Am I right in assuming that if you specify a parent, that child then sits at the grid position you specify in that parent? Here is my example:

```
layout_frame = tk.Frame(master, bg="red").grid(row=1, column=2, rowspan=9, sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.W+tk.E)
inner_frame = tk.Frame(master=layout_frame, bg="red").grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=9, sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.W+tk.E)
```

My problem is that `inner_frame` is sitting at grid position (0,0) in master, and not in `layout_frame`. Why is it not sitting at position (0,0) in it's specified parent?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`layout_frame` is the result of the call to `grid` (which is None and not the frame you have just created). When the parent of a widget is None, Tkinter sets the parent as the root element, so you have to create the frame first and call `grid` in a separate statement.

```
layout_frame = tk.Frame(master, bg="red")
layout_frame.grid(row=1, column=2, rowspan=9, sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.W+tk.E)
inner_frame = tk.Frame(master=layout_frame, bg="red")
inner_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=9, sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.W+tk.E)
```

Comment: Of course! Thankyou very much, can't believe I missed that..!